# How can I read commands coming over serial port with openHAB?

Tags: openhab

these are the write commands towards a serial port:

sendCommand(SendCOM3,"hallo\r\r")            --- text format

sendCommand(SendCOM4,"\u0001\u0012\u0123\u000F\r\r")   --- binary format

and works fine.

Now, who can tell me what I have to do to get the response message over the same serial port ?

Thanks
Ciao
marco

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already writing to the port, I'm assuming you have the serial binding as an addon and the serial ports enabled.

Create a new item and bind it to the serial port to assign incoming data. For example,

```
String Hallo1 "Hallo [%s]" (hall0) {serial="SendCOM3"}
```

The data is a string that you'll need to parse. Restart OpenHAB, check the logs and you should see your item updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add serial binding .jar file to your addons directory

```
org.openhab.binding.serial-1.7.1.jar
```

And add item to yourschema.items:

```
String MySerialDevice "MySerialDevice [%s]" { serial="/dev/ttyUSB0" }
```

change ttyUSB0 to your real tty serial device.